# Visual studio 2013 express Multilingual App Toolkit Could not find resource.dll

Tags: visual-studio, multilingual, toolkit

I just installed the Microsoft Multilingual App Toolkit for my windows application.
Target framework 4

The installation went well.
But than when I tried the project I get this message:
Could not find file 'obj\Release\qps-ploc\Appname.resources.dll'.

The error message is correct, the file is not there, even the folder it should be in, wasn't generated.
I manually created the folder and tried to build the project, with no luck, same error.
So I thought, lets add the wanted languages, and remove the psuedo language.
But that wasn't possible, and now I have 3 error messages.
One for each language.

Than I tried to Rebuild and Clean the Solution, but both didn't solved the problem.
Also a google search didn't gave me a solution, which can also be a problem of non native english search terms.

So my question is, how can I generate the required resource.dll?

EDIT:
I just copied a dll file to the folder, and renamed it to the needed filenname, now the project is building again, and I'll have a look for other problems and if it really works.
But surely, there must be a right way to achieve this?

Comment: You missed a step somewhere, hard to see it from here.  Use the [how-to article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj569303.aspx).  Make sure you saw the "Multilingual App Toolkit was successfully enabled on the selected project" message.

Comment: @Hans, I did saw that message.

I just did it all over again, and same error occured.
Another thing what I observed, was that only 1 file, has translatable entries, all other auto generated translation files are empty.